# Retrieving data in lambda from API-Gateway

Tags: javascript, json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying getting data from the API-Gateway in Lambda and store it in dynamoDB. My code s
nippets are as follows:

Lambda

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB({region: 'eu-central-1', apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    const currentTime = new Date().toISOString();
    const _id = currentTime + "-" + ('-'+Math.random()).substr(3);
    const params = {
        Item: {
            "_id": {
                S: _id
            },
            "dailyRentalRate": {
                N: event.dailyRentalRate
            },
            "title": {
                S: event.title
            },
            "numberInStock": {
                N: event.numberInStock
            },
            "updated": {
                S: currentTime
            }
        },
        TableName: "vidly_movies"
    };

    dynamodb.putItem(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            callback(err);
        } else {
            console.log(data);
            callback(null, data);
        }
    });
};
```

Then I send the following JSON from the Gateway to Lambda:

```
{
    "_id": "sd5sfdg46a",
    "dailyRentalRate": 5,
    "title": "something",
    "numberInStock": 5,
    "updated": "2020-03-19"
}
```

So far so good. Everything works fine.
Now I want to send a JSON with a child like this:

```
{
    "_id": "sd5sfdg46a",
    "dailyRentalRate": 5,
    "title": "something",
    "numberInStock": 5,
    "updated": "2020-03-19",
    "genre": {
        "_id": "asdaga",
        "name": "Action"
    }
}
```

I try to fetch the data with this code, which does not work:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB({region: 'eu-central-1', apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    const currentTime = new Date().toISOString();
    const _id = currentTime + "-" + ('-'+Math.random()).substr(3);
    const params = {
        Item: {
            "_id": {
                S: _id
            },
            "dailyRentalRate": {
                N: event.dailyRentalRate
            },
            "title": {
                S: event.title
            },
            "numberInStock": {
                N: event.numberInStock
            },
            "updated": {
                S: currentTime
            },
            "genre": {
                M: {
                    "_id": {
                        S: event.genre._id
                    },
                    "name": {
                        S: event.genre.name
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        TableName: "vidly_movies"
    };

    dynamodb.putItem(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            callback(err);
        } else {
            console.log(data);
            callback(null, data);
        }
    });
};
```

The error ist somewhere here: `event.genre._id` and `event.genre.name`. But I don't know what to use to access the Child.

Comment: Can you print the "event" passed from API Gateway by adding a print statement at the top of the lambda handler "exports.handler"? The output will be in a cloud watch log group of the lambda.

Comment: Also which integration type is used at API Gateway? AWS_PROXY or HTTP_PROXY or AWS? If not yet, please have a look at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-lambda.html to compare.

Comment: I wonder if it is DynamoDB code part that is causing the problem ... what happens if you replace "S: event.genre._id" with a static string "S: "foo" for instance? Does it work?

Comment: when I replace the variable with static code, everything works fine. how do I set a print statement?

Answer (score 0):

Now it works! Same code, nothing changed! I can't blieve it. Nothing changed and it works now.
Thank you anyway mon!

Comment: Thank you. No, I have no deployments at all. Error was during api testing inside AWS.

Comment: Thank you Mark B, but this is not the point. I understand what you describe. The error occured during testing inside AWS (test button in the API), not from outside. So I consider it is not a question about the deployment-stages.